# Can the input for "Lasso" in python contain categorical variables?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lasso-regression

I want to perform multiple linear regression in python with lasso. I am not sure whether the input observation matrix X can contain categorical variables. I read the instructions from here: [lasso in python](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html#sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.fit)

But it is simple and not indicate the types allowed for. For example, my code includes:

```
model = Lasso(fit_intercept=False, alpha=0.01)
model.fit(X, y)
```

In the code above, `X` is an observation matrix with size of n-by-p, can one of the p variables be categorical type?

Comment: No, not just Lasso, entire sklearn doesn't support categorical vars in fit(), predict() functions

Comment: If you want to use categorical features try encoding them into numerical values using `OneHotEncoder` module of `sklearn`, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to represent the categorical variables using 1s and 0s. If your categorical variables are binary, meaning each belongs to one of two categories, then you replace all category A and B variables into 0s and 1s, respectively. If some have more than two categories, you will need to use [dummy variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)).

I usually have my data in a Pandas dataframe, in which case I use `houses = pd.get_dummies(houses)`, which creates the dummy variables.

Answer (score 1):

A previous poster has a good answer for this, you need to encode your categorical variables.  The standard way is one hot encoding (or dummy encoding), but there are a many  methods for doing this.

Here is a good library that has many different ways you can encode your categorical variables.  These are also implemented to work with Sci-kit learn.

https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/